# Use value for a ChoiceField in a template

Tags: django, templates, choicefield

I have something like this:

forms.py:

```
AVATAR_CHOICES = (('1','option1'), ('2','option2'), ('3','option3'), 
('4','option4'))

class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    avatar = ChoiceField(widget=RadioSelect, choices=AVATAR_CHOICES)
```

I'm passing `form` from my view:

views.py

```
form = RegistrationForm()
return render_to_response('registration/register.html', {'form': form},
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

into a template like this:

registration.html:

```
{% for radio in form.avatar %}
  <label class="radio">{{ radio.tag }}</label>
{% endfor %}
```

but I'd like to include images in front of these option fields as a way to let the users choose an avatar. However, I don't know how to access keys or values from the tuple `AVATAR_CHOICES`. The main idea is to be able to do something like this:

```
{% for radio in form.avatar %}
      <label class="radio">{{ radio.tag }}</label>
      <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}img/avatars/{{ radio.tag.value }}.jpg"/>
{% endfor %}
```

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams That question is for a model field with choices, while this one is for form fields. AFAIK there's no corresponding `get_XXX_display` for form fields, and if there is, it's (a) a different thing and (b) not immediately obvious how to handle it here.

Comment: Hah. And here I am always accusing others of not reading the question (not that I'm always *wrong* about that, mind you...).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try

```
{{ radio.choice_value }}{# value of the choice of the current input #}
{{ radio.choice_label }}{# label of the choice of the current input #}
{{ radio.choice_index }}{# 0-based index #}
```

Only `choice_label` [gets documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.RadioSelect), but you could safely use it so far.